# Did Varys trust Tyrion after the events of A Storm Of Swords?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Major spoiler for *A Dance With Dragons* ahead.

So Varys sent Tyrion to aid Daenerys and advise her to getting back to Westeros and becoming queen etc. but as we know, he secretly had plans to

> put Aegon on the Throne.

We know that Varys and Illyrio had kept the fact that he was alive very close to their chests, and told almost no one outside of his companions that he was even alive.

But why didn't he tell Tyrion before sending him on his journey?

He sent Tyrion with Jon Connington and Young Griff to go and meet Daenerys, so he had to know he would figure out his identity eventually, or at the very least consider the possibility that he would find out.

**If he trusted Tyrion enough to travel with them, how did he not trust him enough to divulge the secret? Or did he want Tyrion to find out on his own?**

We know that Varys sprang Tyrion before his execution, so we know he at least liked or respected him enough to do it. Even though he says he did it because Jaime asked, if he didn't want to he wouldn't have. He was risking a hell of a lot to save Tyrion, he had to have a good reason.

Did he not trust him at that point simply because he went rogue and killed Tywin? Did he consider him a loose cannon?

Comment: My guess would be that he wanted him to find out on his own. Casually dropping the "fact" he was alive would probably make Tyrion less likely to believe it, compared to gradually putting two and two together and reaching the conclusion himself.

Comment: Why did I hover over the spoiler section?? Why?!?!

Comment: Probably not so much wanting Tyrion to find out eventually as gaining his trust initially. This is a drunken broken man we're talking about here who has killed his own father, would you tell him your biggest secret straight off the bat?

Comment: My guess is it was safer this way, if Tyrion found out when in Essos there's less damage he can do to Varys with it, than finding out in Wersteros.

Comment: @Ben That's a good point, so I've changed the question to whether Varys actually trusted Tyrion in general. If he thought he could do damage at all then why would he risk sending him on the journey?

Comment: Well Varys knows exactly how smart Tyrion is. So telling him or not wouldn't make much of a difference anyway. But what if he feared his reaction when tells him he's off to put Aegon on the throne. I think that's the plausible explanation

Comment: Did Varys ever really trust **anyone**?

Comment: @Daft Well the username is a strong hint...

Comment: @Telestia lol :)

Comment: @Daft Re: the spoiler: keep in mind some fans think this subplot might be excised from the TV show, which in itself would be an indication it's a red herring in the books! We do not know *for sure* who Varys really supports at this point; we just know what he claims. And who would blindly trust the Spider? :)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think that trust has anything to do with it. Varys didn't tell Tyrion of the plan for undivulged reasons. It is *very* difficult to know what is going on in Varys' head. Also, at this point, Tyrion hast lost all communication with Varys himself and only deals with Illyrio, perhaps **Illyrio** was the one who didn't trust Tyrion...

Comment: @Mooz that's a really interesting point, I didn't consider that there might be a conflict of interest between Varys and Illyrio. If you can expand that into an answer the bounty is yours!

Comment: @Jaciq agreed, also if we believe in theory that Young Griff is fake Targ and if Tyrion can be deceived then rest (not half as smart as Tyrion) will also swallow the bait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It is unclear whether or not Varys trusts Tyrion; as we do not know the inner workings of Varys' mind, or his ultimate intentions... Yet. But it doesn't matter as Varys didn't have the opportunity to tell Tyrion, therefore the point of Varys trusting Tyrion is moot.**

---

**Little birds can only whisper so far**
This is an interesting case, since after the events of *A Storm of Swords*

> where **Tyrion** kills his own father, [**Tywin**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tywin_Lannister)<sup>[[1]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Storm_of_Swords-Chapter_77)</sup>

**[Tyrion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_Lannister)** gets shipped off to **[Illyrio's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Illyrio_Mopatis)** manse in [Pentos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pentos) in a crate. This is all done very fast and **[Varys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varys)** clearly has no time to tell **Tyrion** anything.

Whilst in Pentos, it is **Illyrio** who introduces **Tyrion** to their Targaryen alliance and "plans"<sup>[[2]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Illyrio_Mopatis#A_Dance_with_Dragons)</sup>, *he* doesn't tell **Tyrion** of the full plans, but that may or may not have had anything to do with trust.

**To tell or not to tell**
**Tyrion** at this point is a broken man. He has been convicted of Regicide (which he happens to not have committed), and is on the run since

> committing Patricide.

He's also drowning in a sea of wine. He most definitely is not in the right mind, nor is he himself.

Whether or not **Varys** and **Illyrio** (Vallyrio) trust him when he his sober, is irrelevant, since **Tyrion** is not going to be of much help, let alone be trustworthy in his drunken stupor.

**Whet his appetite**
You see, **Tyrion** has just lost his right to [Casterly Rock](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Casterly_Rock), and **Illyrio** offers him a chance to win it back; this gets Tyrion going<sup>[[3]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Illyrio_Mopatis#A_Dance_with_Dragons)</sup>.

Once on his way, he slowly discovers that people aren't who they say they are and other mysteries, such as:

> - **Duck** turns out to be Ser **[Rolly Duckfield](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rolly_Duckfield)**
> - **Griff** turns out to be Lord **[Jon Connington](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Connington)**
> - **[Septa Lemore](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lemore)** has had a child previously? Intriguing...

this very much intrigues **Tyrion** and his curiosity; he just can't help trying to solve things and to prove his intellect. Finally he finds out that

> **Young Griff** turns out to be **[Aegon VI Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar))** (questionable, but that's a whole other kettle of fish).

aaaaaaaand he's hooked!

**It's the journey, not the destination**
So, Vallyrio are clever enough to know that **Tyrion** is an asset. He has proven his worth many times over:

- Successfully improving the cisterns and drainage at Casterly Rock<sup>[[4]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Casterly_Rock#History)</sup>
- Successfully evading the death penalty at the Eyrie<sup>[[5]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eyrie#A_Game_of_Thrones)</sup>
- Successfully cleaning up [King's Landing](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/King%27s_Landing) whilst serving as [The Hand of The King](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hand_of_the_King#List_of_Known_Hands)
- Successfully defending King's Landing against one of the most formidable forces to ever engage in war against the city, in The Battle of The Blackwater<sup>[[6]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater)</sup>

Let alone all of his smaller triumphs. So they are ready to utilise him, and they know (especially **Varys** with his many one-on-one dealings with **Tyrion**) that he is very intelligent and capable of leading or at least advising the intendeds, ***but he has to be interested first!*** - hence the "journey" to discover the truth!

Comment: This throws up a lot of interesting points: perhaps Varys was working to get Tyrion kicked out of King's Landing and towards the Targaryens as soon as he realized that he was a true Player of the GoT. He could even have manufactured his demotion from Acting Hand to Master of Coin. I would have accepted this answer just from 'Vallyrio', but the idea that they sent him on the journey *in order* for him to solve the puzzle of who everyone was is great, to get his mind back to solving problems and get him interested in the plot before he finds out the details. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the books we know that Jon Connington and Aegon were sent to meet Daenerys. Which they never did because after their encounter with the Golden Company Aegon decides they should go to Westeros without Daenerys.

So… they’re not following Illyrio’s and Varys’s plan (neither is Daenerys) at all.

From the information in the books, I can surmise that Varys wasn’t *secretly* planning to put Aegon on the throne, but rather reunite the Targaryens in hopes to increase their strength.

Answer (score 0):

Although Varys always states that his motivation is that he is "Loyal to the realm" there is no reason to believe that is his true motivation.  His deeds are always to increase chaos and remove stability even in the days of the mad King.
  There is evidence that he was behind the success of Robert's Rebellion in the form of intelligence.  And the final opening of the city gates to Tywin Lannister. What I mean is that he plays on the Paranoia of King Aerys and allows Pycell to convince the King to open the gates.
  The far fetched machinations of Illyrio and Varys to "Manipulate" first Dany and later Aegon into establishing rule in westeros and at the same time providing a way to do the opposite.  I mean think about it.  Dany is a penniless beggar with no way of being important and she is provided first with Dragons and later a fleet (with merchandize that can be sold) and Barristan the Bold seems like it would be easier to do what she actually did and not go to westeros. Aegon was prepared to go see Dany but is provided with Tyrion who knows the history of Griffin and how things stand in Westeros and what else would they do and go west.
   Once again we have instability in both house Lannister and Targaryan. 
   No, Varys does not trust Tyrion, he is only using him

Comment: "Loyal to the realm" may mean that Varys is loyal to Westoros *as a whole.* He doesn't really care who's on the throne as long as Westeros is united under a good ruler - *any* good ruler - that can get the people through the next Winter. Not out of kindness, but because you can't get taxes or services from dead peasants.

Comment: The true chaos agent is Peter Baelish. Varys acts out of a sense of (some) order and "greater good of the realm" in that he wants a stability that will last, as opposed to a perpetual war. Where Bealish does what he can to _further his own ascension_ by _whatever means necessary_, Varys seeks to _stabilize the realm_ (ultimately decreasing death, one day) by _most_ means.

Comment: As far as I understand Varys was the one who advised Mad king not to open the gates for Lannisters.

Comment: Eric, This discussion is really interesting.  I disagree with the thought that Vary is an agent of stability as he did murder Kevan just to keep the chaos going.  He is an active participant in the chaos of Kings landing.  What makes your point interesting is that I'm not sure if he is a champion of specifically the Targaryen family, or has his own agenda.  However, he definitely does not care about the realm since the chaos he unleashed will cause years of conflict which are far from stability.  I think he is a clever liar